# Python sqlite3 how to pull 100 rows in "quality" column and then change the value of them

Tags: python, sqlite

So I have data and I have a quality column for it. All data starts out with a quality of 1. I want to pull the data and print the 100 rows then change their quality to 2, then 3, then I'm moving them to a new table. I need help with changing and printing their values first.

'''

```
def pull(self,table,quality):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('Emaildatabase.db')
    c = conn.cursor()

    if table == 'Emails':
        c.execute('SELECT * FROM Emails WHERE Quality=(?) LIMIT 100',(quality,))

        data = c.fetchall()
        print(data)
        for row in data:
            print(row)

        if quality == 1:
            c.execute('UPDATE Emails SET Quality=2 WHERE Quality=1')
            conn.commit()
        if quality == 2:
            c.execute('UPDATE Emails SET Quality=3 WHERE Quality=2')
            conn.commit()
        if quality == 3:
            c.execute('UPDATE Emails SET Quality=4 WHERE Quality=3')
            conn.commit()
```

'''

this is what i have so far. when it pulls the data it changes the quality of every value and im not sure where to go from here in terms of making it only change 100 rows per pull.

Comment: please fix the formatting of your question. also change the `if` statements other than the first to be `elif` isntead. th real issue you have here is that you arent trying to update a single row everytime, you try to update all rows with a specific quality, add a unique identifier of some kind, like id or email to the `where` in your if statements

Comment: @Nullman what do i need to fix in the formatting of my question? so i know for future reference and so i can update it. and that makes sense that im selecting all rows and not a single row every time. but im still a little lost, how does adding a unique identifier pull a 100 rows? and are you telling me i need something like " WHERE Quality=3 Emails=X"?

Comment: if you want to change everything then select `distinct` quality, you dont need the whole row and you certainly dont need a bunch of repeating `quality`. the next issue is that if you change all `1` to `2` and then all `2` to `3` then you changed all the `1` to `3`